# How to get TD value using jQuery.?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get value of td using jquery like this.

```
$("#id").find(".class").attr('value'); 
//or
$("#id").find(".class").val();
```

both returns empty string although it has a value.
note* i'm trying get value of dynamically created element. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your html structure

Comment: One can refer to this In-depth article on getting table cell value along with demo https://codepedia.info/jquery-get-table-cell-td-value-div

Answer (score 12):

Just write

```
$("#id .class").text();
```

Or to get the HTML use,

```
$("#id .class").html();
```

Answer (score 6):

The [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea. You need [**text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [**html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function to get the contents of td.

**To get text**

```
textOfTd = $("#id").find(".class").text();
```

**To get Html**

```
textOfTd = $("#id").find(".class").html();
```

Answer (score 6):

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdcls">1</td>
        <td class="tdcls">2</td>
        <td class="tdcls">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdcls">4</td>
        <td class="tdcls">5</td>
        <td class="tdcls">6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery code to select particular `td` value:

```
$(".tdcls").mouseenter(function(){
    var a = $(this).text();
});
```